# Dynamicaly change data in store with ExtJs 3.4

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a store and dynamically change its URL.

```
store_form.proxy.conn.url=url;
store_form.load();
tabs.activate(1);
```

So if I change the URL, data in the store are going to change.

This store I load into `FromPanel`, which is located in a tab:

```
listeners: {
    'activate' :  function(zemform,records,options) {
        console.log("store:"+store_form.getAt(0));
        this.loaded = true;
        var record = store_form.getAt(0);
        zemform.getForm().loadRecord(record);
        //store_form.reload();
    }
},
```

But when the tab is opened, I see previous data. New data show only when I click on another tab and then click back. What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know if I understand you're problem correctly, but I think the problem is the `activate` handler. 
It will be triggered only on activating the tab. You write that the tab is opened already, so it is also activated, the event `activate` won't be triggered in that case.

Instead of that, you should call `loadRecord(record)` in the store `load` handler: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-load